# Не работает сайт на Drupal

Tags: drupal, site, drupal7

Где-то 8 месяцев назад делал клиенту сайт на Друпале 7.56
Неделю назад клиент обратился ко мне что сайт не работает - вернее при заходе на сайт пишет что найдено вредоносный код и браузер его блокирует. 
Первое что сделал - снес старый сайт и с копии, что была у меня на компе востановил (заменил все файлы и базу даных).

Но сайт далее не работает и пишет что найдено вредоносный код. Локально все работает и без ошибок а вот когда кидаю на хостинг показывает ошибку.
Когда устанавливаю чистый друпал все хорошо. Как только добавляю файлы темы и фото, подключаю базу данных - все возвращается назад.

Проверял все файлы по пару раз на наличие ошибок и стороннего кода. Ничего все чисто

Comment: проверьте базу, для начала укажыте что именно выводиться в сообщении кокда сайт не работает

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился со временем,

На сервер был заменён полностью код сайту на чистый Drupal, а через неделю залита копия которая была очищена локально.